# Number of stall cycles when there is only EX/MEM pipeline registers or only MEM/WB pipeline register

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines, mips, assembly

I am working on a problem which is related to The processor. The problem is the problem 4.12 in the book whose title is "Computer Organization and Design". The problem has the assumption as follow:
[image]
Here is an image Figure 4.45
[image]

And the question number 3 makes me stuck on it
[image]

The answer for this problem is MEM/WB has fewer number of stall cycles (which has CPI is 1.35) than EX/MEM (which has CPI is 1.45). I am quite confused with the explanation of this answer.
It states that:

> With forwarding only from the EX/MEM register, EX to 1st dependences
> can be satisfied without stalls but any other dependences (even when
> together with EX to 1st) incur a one-cycle stall. With forwarding only from
> the MEM/WB register, EX to 2nd dependences incur no stalls. MEM to 1st
> dependences still incur a one-cycle stall, and EX to 1st dependences now
> incur one stall cycle because we must wait for the instruction to complete
> the MEM stage to be able to forward to the next instruction

It is correct that with only EX/MEM pipeline register, EX to 1st is solved, however, I can not prove the all of the other cases needs ONLY ONE STALL CYCLE. For example, in the case of MEM to 1st, I think it need for 2 stall cycles because the result now is produced at MEM stage, which does not has any MEM/WB pipeline register to save the result and forward it to the next instruction. Therefore, with 2 more stall cycles, it will have the correct result.

Similarly in the next case of only MEM/WB pipe line register. Do you have any proofs for the explanation of this answer? I really look forward to your answers.

Comment: Can you please show Figure 4.45 too? This would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: @idmean I have added it. Thanks for your feedback and I hope it will work for you

Comment: I don't get it either. With EX/MEM forwarding, "MEM to 1st" should stall for 2 cycles.

Comment: @idmean that's why I found it confusing, however, it is the answer so I think there must be a trick or anything here